# NSLocale Language Names In Local Script

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, locale, nslocale

I am trying to get Xcode to return a list of iOS language names in a variety of formats. In the code below I have created a dictionary returning a variety of strings that I could get returned from NSLocale.

- langInUsersLang - Returns the language name in the users language
- langInLang - Returns the language name in the language

`NSArray *test = [NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers];
NSMutableArray *toBeReturned = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

```
for (int i = 0; i < [test count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary *languageDictionary = @{
                                                @"langInUsersLang" :
                                                    [[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode value:[test objectAtIndex:i]],
                                                @"langInLang" :
                                                    [[NSLocale systemLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode value:[test objectAtIndex:i]],
                                                @"regLangInUsersLang" :
                                                    [[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:[test objectAtIndex:i]],
                                                @"regLangInLang" :
                                                    [[NSLocale systemLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:[test objectAtIndex:i]],
                                                };
    [toBeReturned addObject:languageDictionary];
}
return toBeReturned;
```

Above I was also calling the following, however it seems to return the same content as above, albeit in the reverse order.

```
@"regLangInUsersLang" : [[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:[localIdentifiers objectAtIndex:i]],
@"regLangInLang" : [[NSLocale systemLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:[localIdentifiers objectAtIndex:i]]
```

I need to return the language name in the native script too, any ideas how to?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ah it appears this works:

```
NSLocale *localLocale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:[test objectAtIndex:i]];
```

By not using the current or system Locale but rather the with the language in question then it returns its name in the script!